# joomla direct access to folder for logged users

Tags: joomla

I'm totally scripting noob, so sorry for my question.  I create folder in my joomla instalation. Users should be access to this folder directly but only when they logged in joomla. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

AS indicated in the previous question ([Restrict direct access to script based on joomla authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465478/restrict-direct-access-to-script-based-on-joomla-authentication/3470442#3470442)), you need some sort of a script to serve your files, you cannot give direct access to them. It's best to locate this folder somewhere outside your www root.

Comment: My fault i try put some light on my situation. I have mp3 player on my site, i put mp3 files outside public_html, player needs xml playlist so in xml as location i add mysite/phpscriptfolder/access.php?file=mp3file.mp3, but if some one get xml file he can download file in this way http://mydomain/mysite/phpsciptfolder/access.php?file=mp3file.mp3. First thing i try to is prevent access to folder with xml playlist, second i think to add authentication to access.php, i stuck with this...